# Conditional formatting in Excel: Changing a cell if the the cell directly to the right is the max in a specified range, & the selected cell value ≠ 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Developing spreadsheet to track student loan payments

I tried using a custom formula and inputting MAX for the cell range. For example, the range to be formatted is C31:C38, and the range where I'm looking for the MAX value is D31:D38. I tried the following and nothing was formatted: `AND(C31:C38, MAX(D31:38))`

Comment: `AND($C31<>0, MAX($D$31:$D$38)=$D31)`